# Ubuntu Freezes while using terminal and firefox

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, firefox, freeze, python3

Hi I am extremely new to programming. I downloaded Ubuntu 14.0 and it keeps freezing while I am using firefox and while using the terminal. I would really like for someone to give me some insight into what might be happening. I am using a Samsung laptop and it has Windows7, intel core5 and nvidia graphics card I believe. I installed Ubuntu as a dual OS on my laptop if that makes a difference. Also while in the terminal I was using Python 3.

All suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check in the Additional Drivers utility to find out if there is a proprietary Nvidia graphics driver available to be installed. Also using Python in the terminal is too hard, try installing IDLE and IDLE3 Integrated Development Environment for Python.

Comment: Where do I go to check the additional drivers? @karel

Comment: IDLE and IDLE3 can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center. Additional Drivers utility can be opened by searching for it in the Dash and clicking the Additional Drivers icon. You can also install a graphics driver, if one is available, from Additional Drivers.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I found the additional drivers icon. There is a proprietary Nvidia graphic driver installed, but there are 4 options. I updated the binary driver-version 331.38 from nvidia-331.

Comment: I would go with nvidia-331 over nvidia-331-updates graphics driver unless you have a very new model discrete desktop graphics card, because it is said to be more stable.

Comment: I was already using the nvidia-331 version. I got my laptop in 2011. The only thing I can find on the version of my graphic card is that it says nvidia optimus on my laptop.

Comment: Just a remark, but I am not sure the two are connected by definition. It could very well be that your python code is creating some messed up loop, while firefox freezing is something else. Were you running your own code? (you mention you are new to programming). If so, what was it?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is not an official answer to this question (even thought there are about 10 in the comments), I will tell you your problem. The default nVidia driver that comes with ubuntu (nouveau) is an ingenious piece of junk. If you install the proprietary drivers for you nVidia card, your computer will stop freezing.